# Deserialising nested objects with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am dealing with an API that returns something like this:

```
{"v1.ProjectList": 
    { 
        "self_link": { "href": "https://central-staged:8880/api/v1/projects", "methods": "GET" }, 
        "items": [], 
        "register": {"href": "https://central-staged:8880/api/v1/projects/register", "methods": "POST"}, 
        "max_active": {"href": "https://central-staged:8880/api/v1/projects/max-active", "methods": "GET"} 
    }
}
```

I am generating a bunch of DTOs to accommodate the de-serialisation of of that JSON string.

```
namespace v1
{
    public class Project
    {
        public rest_common.Link branches { get; set; }
        public float coordinate_x { get; set; }
        public float coordinate_y { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public rest_common.Link publish_events { get; set; }
        public rest_common.Link self_link { get; set; }
        public rest_common.Link thumbnail { get; set; }
        public System.Guid uuid { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObject(Title = "v1.ProjectList")]
    public class ProjectList
    {
        public List<Project> items { get; set; }
        public rest_common.Link max_active { get; set; }
        public rest_common.Link register { get; set; }
        public rest_common.Link self_link { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace rest_common
{
    public class Link
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string methods { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That code was generated from server-side code and I can modify it to suit. The only thing I cannot modify at this time is the JSON response returned by the server.

I am trying to figure out how to deserialise this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonContent = "{\"v1.ProjectList\": {\"self_link\": {\"href\": \"https://something.com/getblah\", \"methods\": \"GET\"}, \"items\": [], \"register\": {\"href\": \"https://something.com/postblah\", \"methods\": \"POST\"}, \"max_active\": {\"href\": \"https://something.com/getblah2\", \"methods\": \"GET\"}}}";
            var projectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectList>(jsonContent);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

At the moment `projectList` is an instance of the correct class, but all its members are `null`.

Comment: You should paste a non-escaped JSON example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize an object that contains a single property named `v1.ProjectList`. So create such class:

```
public class ProxyObject
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("v1.ProjectList")]
    public ProjectList ProjectList { get; set;}
}
```

.. And then this works:

```
var projectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProxyObject>(jsonContent).ProjectList;
```

The attribute `[JsonObject(Title = "v1.ProjectList")]` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,
since you are creating a new instance of the class you are deserializing the string of JSON from, indicate that:

```
var projectList = new (ProjectList)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectList>(jsonContent));
```